# Getting this error on Remix "TypeError: Data location must be "memory" or "calldata" for parameter in function,but none was given." compiling contract

Tags: remix, contract-debugging

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.14;

import "./Ownable.sol";
import "./Mtoken.sol";
import "./IERC20.sol";

contract MultiDrop is IERC20, Ownable {
MToken public mtok;
address private _owner;

event MultiERC20Transfer(
    address indexed _from,
    uint indexed _value,
    address _to,
    uint _amount,
    address mtok
);

constructor(MToken _mtok) {
    mtok = _mtok;
    _owner = msg.sender;
   
}

function multiERC20TransferTightlyPacked(
    address mtok, 
    bytes32[] _addressesAndAmounts
) public onlyOwner 
{
    for (uint i = 0; i < _addressesAndAmounts.length; i++) {
        address to = address(_addressesAndAmounts[i] >> 96);
        uint amount = uint(uint96(_addressesAndAmounts[i]));
        _safeERC20Transfer(mtok, to, amount);
        MultiERC20Transfer(msg.sender, msg.value, to, amount, mtok);
    }
}

function multiERC20Transfer( 
    address mtok,
    address[] _addresses,
    uint[] _amounts
) public onlyOwner 
{
    for (uint i = 0; i < _addresses.length; i++) {
        _safeERC20Transfer(mtok, _addresses[i], _amounts[i]);
        MultiERC20Transfer(
            msg.sender,
            msg.value,
            _addresses[i],
            _amounts[i],
            mtok
        );
    }
}
function _safeERC20Transfer(address mtok, address _to, uint _amount)
internal
{
    require(_to != 0);
    require(mtok.transferFrom(msg.sender, _to, _amount));
}

function mtokAvailable() public returns (uint256) {
return mtok.balanceOf(this);
}

function destroy() public onlyOwner {
uint256 balance = mtokAvailable();
require (balance > 0);
mtok.transfer(msg.sender, balance);
selfdestruct(msg.sender);
}
```

}

Comment: Error occuring in the following function:
-multiERC20TransferTightlyPacked
-multiERC20Transfer

Answer (score 0):

The solution should be:

```
function multiERC20TransferTightlyPacked(
address mtok, 
bytes32[] memory _addressesAndAmounts
) public onlyOwner
```

or

```
function multiERC20TransferTightlyPacked(
address mtok, 
bytes32[] calldata _addressesAndAmounts
) public onlyOwner
```

depending on your use-case!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a data location with arrays in the function declaration, in these two functions:

```
function multiERC20TransferTightlyPacked(
    address mtok, 
    bytes32[] memory _addressesAndAmounts
)

OR

function multiERC20TransferTightlyPacked(
    address mtok, 
    bytes32[] calldata _addressesAndAmounts
)
```

```
function multiERC20Transfer( 
    address mtok,
    address[] memory _addresses,
    uint[] memory _amounts
)

OR

function multiERC20Transfer( 
    address mtok,
    address[] calldata _addresses,
    uint[] calldata _amounts
)
```

These Q&A are irrelevant to your question but for information for you as well as for others who will face this, it is relevant. I wrote these in my docs.

Q. Which data types require data location while declaring them?
Ans: Arrays, structs, and mappings require data location when declaring them. But why? Because these are called special types of data types in solidity.

Q. Why do we use data location with strings, when solidity requires data location only with arrays, structs, and mappings?
Ans: Because the string is internally an array of characters.

Q. Can we use storage data location in function parameters? If not then why?
Ans: Solidity knows those function parameters are temporary and do not store anywhere.

Comment: For those who do not know difference between memory and calldata.

We can update/change the variable declared as memory, but we cannot do the same with the variable declared as calldata.